# Arrays.binarySearch not finding the last element

Tags: java

```
char[] charArray = new char[] {'h','e','l','l','o','a'};
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(charArray,'a'));
```

Why it gives me the result as -1 rather than 5?

Comment: Binary search only works on sorted arrays: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

The [`Arrays#binarySearch(char[], char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-char:A-char-) says (in part) *the array must be sorted (as by the [`sort(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-char:A-) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.* Sort your `charArray` first. Like,

```
char[] charArray = new char[] { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'a' };
Arrays.sort(charArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(charArray, 'a'));
```